# Does my code calculate the Entropy/Conditional Entropy of a data set correctly?

Tags: java, machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence, probability

I'm writing a java that I want to use to be able to calculate things like Entropy, Joint Entropy, Conditional Entropy, etc. when given a data set. The class in question is below:

```
public class Entropy {

private Frequency<String> iFrequency = new Frequency<String>();
private Frequency<String> rFrequency = new Frequency<String>();

Entropy(){
    super();
}

public void setInterestedFrequency(List<String> interestedFrequency){
    for(String s: interestedFrequency){
        this.iFrequency.addValue(s);
    }
}

public void setReducingFrequency(List<String> reducingFrequency){
    for(String s:reducingFrequency){
        this.rFrequency.addValue(s);
    }
}

private double log(double num, int base){
   return Math.log(num)/Math.log(base);
}

public double entropy(List<String> data){

    double entropy = 0.0;
    double prob = 0.0;
    Frequency<String> frequency = new Frequency<String>();

    for(String s:data){
        frequency.addValue(s);
    }

    String[] keys = frequency.getKeys();

    for(int i=0;i<keys.length;i++){

        prob = frequency.getPct(keys[i]);
        entropy = entropy - prob * log(prob,2);
    }

    return entropy;
}

/*
* return conditional probability of P(interestedClass|reducingClass)
* */
public double conditionalProbability(List<String> interestedSet,
                                     List<String> reducingSet,
                                     String interestedClass,
                                     String reducingClass){
    List<Integer> conditionalData = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    if(iFrequency.getKeys().length==0){
        this.setInterestedFrequency(interestedSet);
    }

    if(rFrequency.getKeys().length==0){
        this.setReducingFrequency(reducingSet);
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<reducingSet.size();i++){
        if(reducingSet.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(reducingClass)){
            if(interestedSet.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(interestedClass)){
                conditionalData.add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    int numerator = conditionalData.size();
    int denominator = this.rFrequency.getNum(reducingClass);

    return (double)numerator/denominator;
}

public double jointEntropy(List<String> set1, List<String> set2){

    String[] set1Keys;
    String[] set2Keys;
    Double prob1;
    Double prob2;
    Double entropy = 0.0;

    if(this.iFrequency.getKeys().length==0){
        this.setInterestedFrequency(set1);
    }

    if(this.rFrequency.getKeys().length==0){
        this.setReducingFrequency(set2);
    }

    set1Keys = this.iFrequency.getKeys();
    set2Keys = this.rFrequency.getKeys();

    for(int i=0;i<set1Keys.length;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<set2Keys.length;j++){
            prob1 = iFrequency.getPct(set1Keys[i]);
            prob2 = rFrequency.getPct(set2Keys[j]);

            entropy = entropy - (prob1*prob2)*log((prob1*prob2),2);
        }
    }

    return entropy;
}

public double conditionalEntropy(List<String> interestedSet, List<String> reducingSet){

    double jointEntropy = jointEntropy(interestedSet,reducingSet);
    double reducingEntropyX = entropy(reducingSet);
    double conEntYgivenX = jointEntropy - reducingEntropyX;

    return conEntYgivenX;
}
```

For the past few days I've been trying to figure out why my Entropy calculation is almost always exactly the same as my calculation for conditional entropy.

I'm using the following formulas:

H(X) = - Sigma from x=1 to x=n p(x)*log(p(x))

H(XY) = - Sigma from x=1 to x=n,y=1 to y=m (p(x)*p(y)) * log(p(x)*p(y))

H(X|Y) = H(XY) - H(X)

The values that I get for my Entropy and Conditional Entropy are almost the same.

With the data set that I'm using for testing I get the following values:

```
@Test
public void testEntropy(){
    FileHelper fileHelper = new FileHelper();
    List<String> lines = fileHelper.readFileToMemory("");
    Data freshData = fileHelper.parseCSVData(lines);

    LinkedList<String> headersToChange = new LinkedList<String>();
    headersToChange.add("lwt");

    Data discreteData = freshData.discretize(freshData.getData(),headersToChange,1,10);

    Entropy entropy = new Entropy();
    Double result = entropy.entropy(discreteData.getData().get("lwt"));
    assertEquals(2.48,result,.006);
}

@Test
public void testConditionalProbability(){

    FileHelper fileHelper = new FileHelper();
    List<String> lines = fileHelper.readFileToMemory("");
    Data freshData = fileHelper.parseCSVData(lines);

    LinkedList<String> headersToChange = new LinkedList<String>();
    headersToChange.add("age");
    headersToChange.add("lwt");


    Data discreteData = freshData.discretize(freshData.getData(), headersToChange, 1, 10);

    Entropy entropy = new Entropy();
    double conditionalProb = entropy.conditionalProbability(discreteData.getData().get("lwt"),discreteData.getData().get("age"),"4","6");
    assertEquals(.1,conditionalProb,.005);
}

@Test
public void testJointEntropy(){


    FileHelper fileHelper = new FileHelper();
    List<String> lines = fileHelper.readFileToMemory("");
    Data freshData = fileHelper.parseCSVData(lines);

    LinkedList<String> headersToChange = new LinkedList<String>();
    headersToChange.add("age");
    headersToChange.add("lwt");

    Data discreteData = freshData.discretize(freshData.getData(), headersToChange, 1, 10);

    Entropy entropy = new Entropy();
    double jointEntropy = entropy.jointEntropy(discreteData.getData().get("lwt"),discreteData.getData().get("age"));
    assertEquals(5.05,jointEntropy,.006);
}

@Test
public void testSpecifiedConditionalEntropy(){

    FileHelper fileHelper = new FileHelper();
    List<String> lines = fileHelper.readFileToMemory("");
    Data freshData = fileHelper.parseCSVData(lines);

    LinkedList<String> headersToChange = new LinkedList<String>();
    headersToChange.add("age");
    headersToChange.add("lwt");

    Data discreteData = freshData.discretize(freshData.getData(), headersToChange, 1, 10);

    Entropy entropy = new Entropy();
    double specCondiEntropy = entropy.specifiedConditionalEntropy(discreteData.getData().get("lwt"),discreteData.getData().get("age"),"4","6");
    assertEquals(.332,specCondiEntropy,.005);

}

@Test
public void testConditionalEntropy(){

    FileHelper fileHelper = new FileHelper();
    List<String> lines = fileHelper.readFileToMemory("");
    Data freshData = fileHelper.parseCSVData(lines);

    LinkedList<String> headersToChange = new LinkedList<String>();
    headersToChange.add("age");
    headersToChange.add("lwt");

    Data discreteData = freshData.discretize(freshData.getData(), headersToChange, 1, 10);

    Entropy entropy = new Entropy();
    Double result = entropy.conditionalEntropy(discreteData.getData().get("lwt"),discreteData.getData().get("age"));
    assertEquals(2.47,result,.006);
}
```

Everything compiles correctly but I'm pretty sure that my calculations for the conditional entropy are incorrect, but I'm not sure where I'm making a mistake.

The values that are in the unit tests are the values that I'm currently getting. They are the same as the output from the above functions.

At one point I was also using the following to do testing:

```
List<String> survived = Arrays.asList("1","0","1","1","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","1");
List<String> sex = Arrays.asList("0","1","0","1","1","0","0","1","1","0","1","0","0","1","1");
```

Where male = 1 and survived = 1. I then used this to calculate

```
double result = entropy.entropy(survived);
assertEquals(.996,result,.006);
```

as well as

```
double jointEntropy = entropy.jointEntropy(survived,sex);
assertEquals(1.99,jointEntropy,.006);
```

I also checked my work by calculating the values by hand. You can see an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VJkl.jpg). Since my code was giving me the same values that I got when I did the problem by hand and since the other functions were pretty simple and just used the entropy/joint entropy functions I assumed that everything was fine.

However, something is going wrong. Below are two more functions that I wrote to calculate information gain and the symmetrical uncertainty of a set.

```
public double informationGain(List<String> interestedSet, List<String> reducingSet){
    double entropy = entropy(interestedSet);
    double conditionalEntropy = conditionalEntropy(interestedSet,reducingSet);
    double infoGain = entropy - conditionalEntropy;
    return infoGain;
}

public double symmetricalUncertainty(List<String> interestedSet, List<String> reducingSet){
    double infoGain = informationGain(interestedSet,reducingSet);
    double intSet = entropy(interestedSet);
    double redSet = entropy(reducingSet);
    double symUnc = 2 * ( infoGain/ (intSet+redSet) );
    return symUnc;
}
```

The original survive/sex set that I used gave me an answer that was slightly negative. But since it was only negative by .000000000000002 I just assumed that it was a rounding error. When I tried to run my program, none of the values that I got for symmetrical uncertainty made any sense.

Comment: Please show the output of your test runs.  Degenerate cases are simple enough.  For instance, feed it a list of N consecutive integers.  The entropy should be log2(N), right?  Repeat with similar cases, ones that are easily verified with another routine or hand-calculation.

Comment: @Prune That's why I included the tests. The values that are currently listed in the unit tests the values that I'm getting. I calculated the values for Entropy and Joint Entropy by hand so I'm pretty sure that those two functions work correctly. But by the time I'm calculating the symmetrical uncertainty my answers are off. I'm getting negative values when they should be between 0 and 1. I thought that there might be some small thing that I'm missing and I just can't see it because I've just been looking at it so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr; Your calculation for H(X,Y) apparently assumes that X and Y are independent, which results in H(X,Y) = H(X) + H(Y), which in turn results in your H(X|Y) being equal to H(X).

Is this your problem? If so, then use the correct formula for the joint entropy of X and Y (taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_entropy)):

[image]

You get your wrong one by substituting P(X,Y) = P(X)P(Y), which assumes that both variables are independent.

If both variables *are* independent, then indeed H(X|Y) = H(X) holds, because Y doesn't tell you anything about X, and consequently knowing Y doesn't decrease the entropy of X.

Comment: That is pretty much my problem. What is the correct formula? I've only been able to find [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_entropy) one on Wikipedia. My prob theory book doesn't have anything on the subject so wikipedia is pretty much what I've been using.

Comment: @j.jerrod.taylor The one in your link is correct. See my edit.

Comment: That makes sense. I see where I messed up now.

Answer (score 1):

For calculating Entropy of single vector you can use below function

```
Function<List<Double>, Double> entropy = 
    x-> {
        double sum= x.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
        return - x.stream()
                    .map(y->y/sum)
                    .map(y->y*Math.log(y))
                    .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                    .sum();
    };
```

As an example using vector [1 2 3] would get you a result of 1.0114

```
double H = new Entropy().entropy.apply(Arrays.asList(new Double[] { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }));
System.out.println("Entropy H = "+ H);
```